# SQL Server issue updating multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why doesn't this not work?

```
update UserBank 
set BankId = 'ED4E60CA-5068-42F8-BCB3-A5BC1228D546' 
where BankId in (select Id from Bank where Name = 'A Bank')
```

There are multiple banks in the Bank table named 'A Bank' so the subquery returns a list of unique identifiers.

I want to update all of the records in the UserBank table with the new id if their current BankId is in that list of unique identifiers.

I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: You may want to check if there's a badly written trigger on the table that doesn't account for more than one row getting updated.

Comment: It was a trigger causing the issue.  Thanks Jeroen

Answer (score 1):

A trigger on the UserBank table was causing the issue